# The fetch() function in the JS code embedded in Java does not work

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, fetch-api, graalvm

I need to execute Javascript code inside Java. For this, I use the GraalVM engine, where I installed a plugin to execute Javascript. Everything is fine, except for the problem with the fetch() function I'm using in the JS code. It is not defined in the Graal engine (as I read, it is not part of "pure" Javascript).

I installed Node.js and then using the command 'npm install fetch-node' in the project directory I installed this library.
Next, using the code below, I managed to use the require() function. The only remaining problem is that the program throws an exception

> Exception in thread "main" SyntaxError: D:\folder\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js:9:0 Expected an operand but found import
> import http from 'node:http';

And I didn't find a solution for it on the internet.

```
// java static fields
    public static Context context;
    public static Value invokeFunction;

// java static method' part
 context = Context.newBuilder("js")
                .allowExperimentalOptions(true)
                .allowIO(true)
                .option("js.commonjs-require", "true")
                .option("js.commonjs-require-cwd", "D:/folder/fetch_node")
                .option("js.commonjs-core-modules-replacements",
                        "buffer:buffer/," +
                                "path:path-browserify")
                .build();

        invokeFunction = context.eval("js","let fetch = require('node-fetch');\n");
```

the part of index.js:

```
import http from 'node:http';
import https from 'node:https';
import zlib from 'node:zlib';
import Stream, {PassThrough, pipeline as pump} from 'node:stream';
import {Buffer} from 'node:buffer';

import dataUriToBuffer from 'data-uri-to-buffer';

import {writeToStream, clone} from './body.js';
import Response from './response.js';
import Headers, {fromRawHeaders} from './headers.js';
import Request, {getNodeRequestOptions} from './request.js';
import {FetchError} from './errors/fetch-error.js';
import {AbortError} from './errors/abort-error.js';
import {isRedirect} from './utils/is-redirect.js';
import {FormData} from 'formdata-polyfill/esm.min.js';
import {isDomainOrSubdomain, isSameProtocol} from './utils/is.js';
import {parseReferrerPolicyFromHeader} from './utils/referrer.js';
import {
    Blob,
    File,
    fileFromSync,
    fileFrom,
    blobFromSync,
    blobFrom
} from 'fetch-blob/from.js';
```

Comment: @Rajesh I know, I've already tested that js code in the browser, but I just need to execute it in Java. In short, there you need to make a GET request to a certain website, process it and then return true/false.